# Force Eclipse to execute a multi-threaded Java program single threaded

Tags: eclipse, multithreading

Is there a way to force Eclipse or JVM to serialize a multi-thread Java program?

Comment: I don't understand this question, do you want to capture the current program state so that you can resume execution later? Or something else? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I have some System.out.println(SOMETHING) and I would like that SOMETHING wasn't divided in many tokens. Actually I am realizing that I should put some wait and locks. I was in a hurry and I tried to be too fast.

Comment: Yes, read up on Java synchronization.

Comment: Thanks. I got what I wanted just using the Debugging function of Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you do something clever by overriding the Thread class.